# In what situation would it be more beneficial to use AutoFS over vfstab for shares dedicated to just one server?

Tags: solaris, automounting, autofs

Consider an environment of three Solaris servers (Server1-3):

1. Where Server1-3 all share a mount `nas-server.company.com:/vol/appls-backup`, for storing backups and recovery related files at periodic intervals (once every few hours).

   - Here I think the choice of using AutoFS has obvious advantages - here the automounter has the purpose of conserving local system resources and of reducing the coupling between systems which share filesystems with a number of servers [[Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automounter)].
2. Now each server has a share mounted onto some mount-point where the application assemblies and live data is located. I placed these mounts in `/etc/vfstab` so the mounting would occur once on system boot. As they are accessed continuously, AutoFS might cause delays if it automatically un-mounted the share at some time.

Now for case #2, in what situation would AutoFS be more desirable or required than using vfstab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always want to use AutoFS if the storage resource is not up when a system boots. This is one of the primary functions that AutoFS provides. Without it a server will attempt to mount a storage resource, timeout, and never try again if you just mount it at boot up.

Additionally AutoFS allows you the ability to take the storage backend down and the clients will essentially wait forever until it comes back.

This [Red Hat Storage Admin Guide](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/s1-nfs-client-config-autofs.html) pretty much sums it up.

Additionally AutoFS isn't just for automounting NFS shares, you can use it to automount most things including CIFS (Samba), and even seldom used ISO files for Linux Distros, for example.